# Try to lower bandwidth requirements for Framebuffer based command

Tags: javascript, decimal, framebuffer

HEX Code Generation Function J=2bits=3 bitwidth=3bit=4 Q=1(constant with shift) to Output 4Bits Compression 5->64

```
    B1=0000 zeroes(bitwidth) 0bit
    B2=0001= edram(zeroes(bitwidth)) 0bit
    B3=0010= sigmund(bitwidth) 0bit
    B4=0011= J 0bit
    B5=0100= bitwidth 0bit
    B6=0101= edram(bitwidth) 0bit
    B7=0110= shift(J,Q) 0bit
    B8=0111= shift(J,Q)++ 0bit
    S9=1000=shift(bitwidth,Q) 0bit
    S10=1001= shift(bitwidth,Q)++ 0bit
    S11=1010=shift(edram(bitwidth),Q) 0bits
    S12=1011=shift(edram(bitwidth)),Q)++0bit
    S13=1100=shift(edram2S(bitwidth)),Q) 0bit
    S14=1101=shift(edram2S(bitwidth)),Q)++;0bit
    S15=1110=shift(ones(J),Q) 0bit
    S16=1111=shift(ones(J),Q)++ 0bit
```

Type B you output as code in HEX which draws the image Type S you handle with a 2bit function and ++. Compression is for animation. How would i set up the HEX image FILE in javascript.

What I think I'm after is how to Code The compressed Hex Code to compile JIT to each 4bit-12 bit value? then rendering will take the 12 bit code and output HSLA=(17 hue,3 Sat,5 Lum,16 Alpha) in RGBA

Comment: What I'm trying to do is compress animation so my code would look like this

Comment: F(5bit when 1 0 or null and whether ++ on first 4bit)=(12bit of previous) +=(16++) all how needed 2.4 to one on commands about 10

Comment: 8bit=240combinations command with to 5 bit with 1,0,null

(BorS)BB=5bit=12bit+(16++)

(BorS)SS=5bit=12bit+(16++)

(BorS)BS=5bit=12bit+(16++)

(BorS)SB=5bit=12bit+(16++)

or

last 4bit

Comment: `boolean animation[1280000]
for (for a=0 a<1280000 a+=5){
var value;

switch(commandstring){
case 0: switch(animation[a]){
case 0:
value=function A81(animation[a+1],animation[a+2],animation[a+3],animation[a+4]){}
case 1:
...
}
}
switch(value%4){
case 0:
value=value>>value%16
case 1:
value+256;
case 2:
value+257;
default:
value++;
}
//outpuutting color
var r=imageData.data[4*ansy];
var g=imageData.data[4*ansy+1];
var b=imageData.data[4*ansy+2];
var a=16-(value%16)
data[i] = (a << 24) | 
(b << 16) | 
(g << 8) | 
r;
}
//funcA81=repeated 3 part switch 3^4
...`

Comment: I'm trying to learn what JIT compiler will solve the 12 bit FuncA-L81 which is essentially a three leaf tree

Comment: Discussion: https://www.gamedev.net/topic/685447-working-on-8-bit-animation-engine-for-javascript-want-to-know-what-12-16bit-varible-will-be-simplified-and-compressed-with-interpolation-and-jit/